# flattening Json from Varchar Array athena

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

Trying to explode array with json values though `values is in string datatype in the table`

```
id   values

1   [{"entity_id":9222.0,"entity_name":"A","position":1.0,"entity_price":133.23,"entity_discounted_price":285.0},{"entity_id":135455.0,"entity_name":"B","position":2.0,"entity_price":285.25},{"entity_id":9207.0,"entity_name":"C","position":3.0,"entity_price":55.0}]
2   [{"entity_id":9231.0,"entity_name":"D","position":1.0,"entity_price":130.30}]
```

Expected Result

```
id entity_id entity_name position entity_price entity_discounted_price

1  9222      A           1        133.23       285.0
1  135455    B           2        285.25       null
1  9207      C           3        55.0         null
2  9231      D           1        130.30       null
```

What I have tried

```
select a.*
,sites.entity_id
,sites.entity_name
,sites.position
,sites.entity_price
,sites.entity_discounted_price 
from (select * from table1) a , unnest(cast(values as array(varchar))) as t(sites)
```

above code is throwing error `Cannot cast varchar to array(varchar)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast `varchar` to `array(varchar)`. In this particular case you can use [`json_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse) and process the json, for example by casting into `array(map(varchar, json))`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(id, "values") AS (
    VALUES (1, '[{"entity_id":9222.0,"entity_name":"A","position":1.0,"entity_price":133.23,"entity_discounted_price":285.0},{"entity_id":135455.0,"entity_name":"B","position":2.0,"entity_price":285.25},{"entity_id":9207.0,"entity_name":"C","position":3.0,"entity_price":55.0}]'),
(2, '[{"entity_id":9231.0,"entity_name":"D","position":1.0,"entity_price":130.30}]')
)

-- query
select id
     , sites['entity_id']
     , sites['entity_name']
     , sites['position']
     , sites['entity_price']
     , try(sites['entity_discounted_price'])
from dataset,
     unnest(cast(json_parse("values") as array(map(varchar, json)))) as t(sites);
```

Output:

| id | _col1 | _col2 | _col3 | _col4 | _col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9222.0 | A | 1.0 | 133.23 | 285.0 |
| 1 | 135455.0 | B | 2.0 | 285.25 | NULL |
| 1 | 9207.0 | C | 3.0 | 55.0 | NULL |
| 2 | 9231.0 | D | 1.0 | 130.3 | NULL |

Comment: Can you please explain what was the issue with my code? and moreover if I use `sites.entity_id` instead of `sites['entity_id']`, it is throwing me error of `Expression sites is not of type ROW`

Comment: @loving_guy `.` syntax is used to access fields of [`ROW`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#row) type.